# How to Pattern Match a left Parenthesis and specific characters after

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

Simply enough, I am trying to find a Pattern where if there is an equation that has a ( and check if after that ( there is a + or - or * or /, one example is

4 + 3 * (+2/1 + 3) * 1   <--- where the (+2 would be what the pattern finds and I can use this to test a equation if it is in valid form (the valid form would be 4 + 3 * (2/1+3) * 1 )

This is in Java

Comment: Can your text contain nested parenthesis?

Comment: I tried

    Pattern y = Pattern.compile("[(].*?");
    Pattern z = Pattern.compile("([(][+-/*].*?");
    Pattern a = Pattern.compile("\\([+-/*].*?");
    Pattern b = Pattern.compile("(/().*?"); 

and more variations of those combinations

Comment: @Pshemo yes, I believe so. Just think of any expression

((((5/9)+6)-4)/1) or 54-2*(23-2)/2 but at any time they cant be any symbol after the left parentheses such that 54-2*(-23-2)/2 is wrong

Comment: I'd say regex isn't the right tool for this job. You should instead write a proper recursive parser.

Comment: could you explain more? I am still trying to learn this stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this parser. It implements following grammar

```
number := [0-9]+ 
expression := '(', expression, ')', op | number, op
op := '+', expression | '-', expression | '/', expression | '*', expression | epsilon
```

in the pseudo EBNF

```
public class ExpressionParser {
    private enum Type {
        LB, RB, NUMBER, OP, END
    }

    private static class Token {
        Type type;
        String value;
        int current;

        public Token(Type type, String value, int current) {
            super();
            this.type = type;
            this.value = value;
            this.current = current;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Token [type=" + type + ", value=" + value + ", current="
                    + current + "]";
        }

    }

    private static class Lexer {

        private int current;
        private String input;

        public Lexer(String input) {
            this.input = input;
        }

        private char getChar() {
            return input.charAt(current++);
        }

        private void unputChar() {
            current--;
        }

        private boolean hasNextChar() {
            return current < input.length();
        }

        Token next() {

            if (!hasNextChar()) {
                return new Token(Type.END, "", current);
            }

            char c = getChar();

            while (Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
                c = getChar();
            }

            if (c == '(') {
                return new Token(Type.LB, "(", current);
            }

            if (c == ')') {
                return new Token(Type.RB, ")", current);
            }

            if (c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '*' || c == '/') {
                return new Token(Type.OP, "" + c, current);
            }

            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            while (hasNextChar()) {

                c = getChar();

                if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                    buffer.append(c);
                } else {
                    unputChar();
                    break;
                }

            }

            return new Token(Type.NUMBER, buffer.toString(), current);

        }
    }

    private static boolean match(Type type) {
        return type == currentToken.type;
    }

    private static void consume(Type type) {
        if (!match(type)) {
            throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Should be %s is %s",
                    type.name(), currentToken.toString()));
        }
        currentToken = lexer.next();
    }

    private static void operation() {

        if (match(Type.OP)) {
            consume(Type.OP);
            expression();
        }

    }

    private static void expression() {

        while (!match(Type.END)) {

            if (match(Type.NUMBER)) {
                consume(Type.NUMBER);
                operation();
            } else if (match(Type.LB)) {
                consume(Type.LB);
                expression();
                consume(Type.RB);
                operation();
            } else {
                break;
            }

        }

    }

    private static Lexer lexer;
    private static Token currentToken;

    private static void parse(String line) {

        lexer = new Lexer(line);
        currentToken = lexer.next();

        try {
            expression();
            consume(Type.END);
            System.out
                    .println(String.format("%s is a proper expression", line));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(String.format(
                    "%s is not a proper expression because %s", line,
                    e.getMessage()));
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        parse("4 + 3 * (+2/1 + 3) * 1");
        parse("4 + 3 * (2/1+3) * 1");
        parse("((((5/9)+6)-4)/1)");
        parse("54-2*(23-2)/2");
        parse("54-2*(-23-2)/2");

    }
}
```

Output

```
4 + 3 * (+2/1 + 3) * 1 is not a proper expression because Should be RB is Token [type=OP, value=+, current=10]
4 + 3 * (2/1+3) * 1 is a proper expression
((((5/9)+6)-4)/1) is a proper expression
54-2*(23-2)/2 is a proper expression
54-2*(-23-2)/2 is not a proper expression because Should be RB is Token [type=OP, value=-, current=7]
```